# Multiple custom Converters for the same class is not possible in Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

Given that I have 2 domain classes

```java
@Document(indexName="domain1")
class Domain1 {
  @JsonSerialize(using = CompanyIdJsonSerializer.class) // serialize to {"id", <number>}
  private Company company;
}

@Document(indexName = "domain2")
class Domain2 {
  @JsonSerialize(using = CompanyIdNameJsonSerializer.class) // serialize to {"id", <number>, "name": <string>}
  private Company company;
}
```

How can this be achieved in Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.1 since Jackson is no more supported?

The ElasticsearchCustomConversions bean is defined globally and it doesn't seem to be able to define different custom conventions for the same Domain object.

Comment: Are you storing the the same domain objects in two indices? If yes, why two different indices? If no, why do you use the same domain class for different objects?

Comment: Both Domain1 and Domain2 reference the company object. When index domain1 and domain2 I would like to store only the company.id so that I can filter by company.id to ensure that members of company A can only access data in company A. 

The problem appears when I want to index the company data in its own index so that I can search by company.

```
@Document(indexName="company")
class Company {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
}
```

Comment: sorry, I still don't understand why you want one index with only the id and one with id and name.